# Using regex with python to find unique number format

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, format, set

I have a very large text file (45000 lines) with ID #'s in the format of 4 or 5 numbers followed by 2 or 3 numbers and then a letter sometimes trailing at the end.

Sample example formats:

XXXX-XX XXXXX-XX ,XXXXX-XXw, XXXXX-XXw, XXXXX-XXww

((Where w is a letter and X is a number))

Most of the values are in the format of #####-## or ####-##, but a large chunk have 1 or more letter trailing at the end.

What I want to do: Whenever there is a value that has a letter at the end I want to store it in a dictionary and keep track of all the unique values of letters that diverge from the normal format, and then print that dictionary.

So for values like: 11111-12s or 1111-12a or 11234-24b I want to store the letter values (s, a , b) and see the differences. What I have currently just displays the values and also repeats:

```
import re

sampleFile = open("Sample.txt", "r")

#regEX formats
sample = re.compile(r'(\d{4,5}-\d\d\w{1,4})')

for line in sampleFile:
    sampleNum = sample.findall(line)
    for word in sampleNum:
        print word
```

How would I go about doing this targeting unique values of the w{1,4} portion of the regex and storing them in a dict?

EDIT:When I run above this is a sample of numbers I get:

12647-01a
12627-02R
12606-01a
12588-02a
12583-01S
12583-01R

So those values at the end vary, and I just want to store the end letter (sometimes there is 2 or more) in a dict or set. Hope this helps

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? You want to have something like `s -> [1111-12], a->[1111-12], b->[11234-24]` OR `1111-12->[s,a], 11234-24->[b]` ?

Comment: The format is 11111-12  and 3424-32 but sometimes there is a letter at the end like 23242-32s or 34343-23b or 2234-22a or sometimes 2 letters 14343-32RA and such. For the letter portion, and only the letter portion, I want to store those unique values/entries then print said values. There are many variations (a ,b ,ba ,c, R, RA, s, aaa etc) I only want to know the letter(s) at the end and how many unique variations occur. Understand?

Comment: is **[this](https://regex101.com/r/dA8eF1/1)** good?

Comment: I wrote it as so: sample1 = re.compile(r'(\d{4,5}-\d{2,3}\[^\s]+)') I get no values returned for this, maybe I didnt input it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple set which reads your regex should match your clarified comment:

```
import re
uniq = set()
with open('Sample.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        ma = re.search(r'(\w{1,4})$', line)
        if not ma:
            continue
        uniq.add(ma.group(1))

print(uniq)
```

Comment: what is the group portion doing ma.group(1,2) ? Getting run time error: 
IndexError: no such group

Comment: Values are stored in `uniq`. If you want to see the values, add `print(uniq)`

Comment: this is pretty much what i needed! But it is also printing just numbers at the end, but overall it has made everything easier, thanks.